# Thread listener notification

Tags: java, multithreading, handle

I'm having a problem with class which handles thread complete. It schould notify other threads that are fineshed so the second one can start. This is my project structure:

**MainClass.java**

```
public class MainClass implements ThreadCompleteListener {

public void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    NotifyingThread test = new Thread1();
    test.addListener((ThreadCompleteListener) this); 
    test.start();         

}

@Override
public void notifyOfThreadComplete(Thread thread) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}   

}
```

**Class - Thread1.java**

```
public class Thread1 extends NotifyingThread {

@Override
public void doRun() {
    try {
        metoda();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static synchronized void metoda() throws InterruptedException {
    for(int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
        Thread.sleep(500);
        System.out.println("method in Thread1");
    }
}

public void notifyOfThreadComplete(Thread thread) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

**NotifyingThread.java**

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArraySet;

public abstract class NotifyingThread extends Thread {
  private final Set<ThreadCompleteListener> listeners = new  CopyOnWriteArraySet<ThreadCompleteListener>();
  public final void addListener(final ThreadCompleteListener listener) {
    listeners.add(listener);
  }

  public final void removeListener(final ThreadCompleteListener listener) {
    listeners.remove(listener);
  }

  private final void notifyListeners() {
    for (ThreadCompleteListener listener : listeners) {
      listener.notifyOfThreadComplete(this);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public final void run() {
    try {
      doRun();
    } finally {
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

  public abstract void doRun();
}
```

**ThreadCompleteListener.java**

```
public interface ThreadCompleteListener {
void notifyOfThreadComplete(final Thread thread);
}
```

Problem which I face is that when I execute MainClass I'm getting an error like: Fatal exception occured. Program will exit and in console appears:

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main
Exception in thread "main"

Could anyone help to get this in one working peace or tell what I'm doing wrong in the code?

Many thanks for any advice!

Comment: notifyOfThreadComplete is empty. It's not the cause of the error, but it's not going to work as you expect.

Answer (score 7):

replace **public void main**

with **public `static` void main**

Comment: When I replace public void main with public static void main I can't use test.addListener((ThreadCompleteListener) this); because I'm getting that it can not be use in static contex

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out.... Your advice about Google Search Box was soooo helpful... It's such a extended tool isn't ?!

Comment: @MisterS Of course you will get an error!! you need to replace `this` with `new MainClass()`

Answer (score 2):

I think you should replace:

```
public void main(String[] args)
```

for

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```